# +=(relation) the meaning of code for selection process

Tags: c++, selection-sort

**counter += (a1<=x);**

what this code statement says ?

it is used in a problem to get how many numbers is lower than or equal (x) variable,

this should be as comparison between a1 and a2 to get what is less than or equal variable x

Comment: This is the kind of code written by people who think they can outsmart current compilers. And no they can't just write `if (a1<x)`. Trust your compiler to generate optimized cod for you see : https://godbolt.org/z/KW4sehhjr

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Umm... Are you sure that link says what you think it says? They actually produced different output (which mildly surprises me, I'd assumed they'd produce the same thing), and there's no obvious way to tell which is faster. It's almost certainly contextual; if half the values lead to an increment, and half don't, and the order is random, the `counter += a1 <= x;` code is likely to win (due to branch mispredictions in the `if`-based code). If 99% of the values, or long runs of the values, always test the same way, `if (a1 <= x) ++counter;` *might* win by a tiny bit.

Comment: [Branch misprediction causes real problems in some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/364696), and it is in fact fixed by rewriting it as branchless code.

Comment: Don't write code like this.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Me bad, You're absolutely right missed branch predictions are bad. Still if performance isn't an issue I'd opt for the more readable version. (next step might be to add [[likely]],[[unlikely]] hints)

Answer (score 0):

It feels like an unnecesssarily complicated way of saying:

```
if(a1 <= x) counter++;
```

If we are to believe that "true" defaults to "1" and "false" defaults to "0" when converting boolean to int.

Comment: It's not a matter of belief, it's the language standard. It's not "unnecessarily complicated", it's just another way to spell it, one that, on older, bad compilers, *might* have made the difference between conditional branching over an increment and branchless adding of the result of the comparison, but basically every modern compiler will likely recognize the two as equivalent and choose whichever implementation makes sense for the architecture (possibly changing as a result of profile-guided optimization, depending on how well branching is predicted).

Comment: If `counter`, `a1`, or `x` are user-defined types, then your `if`-statement could be wildly different than what's actually produce.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is a worse kind to write it down :  With an explicit `if` and without implicit (bool to int) conversion  the code is both more readable and can even result in better compiled code. So Dark rebellion is right.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Huh? Not sure what you're trying to say. You can argue readability if you like, but I consider both equally readable; boolean operations produce `1` or `0` in C (and C++, Python, effectively so in Perl, etc., etc.), so adding them up is a perfectly reasonable way to sum the result of many such comparisons. I wouldn't blink twice at either formulation.

Comment: (Well, I'd side-eye unnecessary use of postfix increment pretty hard, because as a C++ programmer, it sets off code smell alarms, but aside from that...)

Comment: Gotta correct my earlier statement: Based on Pepijn's link, they might not compile to the same code (at least in isolation; PGO or code with different structure might cause them to do so). And the branchless code might actually be faster [depending on patterns in the input data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/364696). Point is, it actually is a real choice, and it can make meaningful difference in performance.